# Combine pre-joined tables with another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, inner-join, union-all

I am trying to join a pre-joined table with another table side by side, but it doesnt seem to work.

Here's the code :

```
SELECT
  r.domainid,
  r.dombegin AS DomainStart,
  r.domend AS Domain_End,
  d.ddid,
  d.confid1 AS confid,
  c.pdbcode,
  c.chainid,
  a.pdbcode AS "cath_pdbcode", 
  c.pdbcode
FROM dyn_dyndomrun d, cath_domains a
  INNER JOIN dyn_conformer c ON d.confid1 = c.id
  INNER JOIN dyn_domainregion r ON r.domainid::varchar(8) = d.ddid
  INNER JOIN dyn_conformer AS c ON a.pdbcode::character(4) = c.pdbcode
UNION ALL
SELECT
  NULL,
  NULL,
  NULL,
  NULL,
  NULL,
  d.ddid,
  d.confid2,
  c.pdbcode,
  c.chainid
FROM dyn_dyndomrun d 
  INNER JOIN dyn_conformer c ON d.confid2 = c.id
  ORDER BY confid ASC
```

There is something wrong at this line

```
FROM dyn_dyndomrun d, cath_domains a
      INNER JOIN dyn_conformer c ON d.confid1 = c.id
      INNER JOIN dyn_domainregion r ON r.domainid::varchar(8) = d.ddid
      INNER JOIN dyn_conformer AS c ON a.pdbcode::character(4) = c.pdbcode
```

Here's the error :

```
ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "d"
LINE 11:   INNER JOIN dyn_conformer c ON d.confid1 = c.id
                                         ^
HINT:  There is an entry for table "d", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.


********** Error **********

ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "d"
SQL state: 42P01
Hint: There is an entry for table "d", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
Character: 236
```

At the end, I would like to have a table in which it has, `"domainid, domainstart, domainend, ddid, confid, chainid, pdbcode from conformer and the chain id"` and along side that, i would like to have a new set of columns from another table, such as `"pdbcode from cath_domains, cathbegin, cathend"`.

The pdbcode from conformer and cath_domains match each other and therefore i would like to cross-reference them.

Am I doing it the wrong way?

Comment: Care to post the error you encountered?

Comment: `ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "d"
LINE 11:   INNER JOIN dyn_conformer c ON d.confid1 = c.id
                                         ^
HINT:  There is an entry for table "d", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.


********** Error **********

ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "d"
SQL state: 42P01
Hint: There is an entry for table "d", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
Character: 236`

Comment: posted the error in my question, aswell

Comment: Try using unique aliases. Your query defines table `d` twice.

Comment: how do i do that, please advise. Thank you. It gave an error as when i called out to table together in the "FROM" clause, `"dyn_dyndomrun d, cath_domains a"`

Comment: Try changing your **second** from clause. `FROM dyn_dyndomrun d2`, etc.

Comment: same problem. It hasn't changed since then. Would it be easier, if i just turned the first bit of the pre-joined tables into a view and then from there, call the second table out as normal with one single inner join ? or is there another way ?

Comment: Probably due to the fact that you're selecting from two base table. Start your FROM using one of the two tables and INNER JOIN to the other.

Comment: I have managed to solve it, using a view table for the pre-joined table and then called out join on it for the other set of table. Thank you for help. Much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2):

Stop doing implicit cross joins.  Also as ypercube pointed out, a few other little things need to be cleaned up, particularly removing the duplicate join.

```
SELECT
  r.domainid,
  r.dombegin AS DomainStart,
  r.domend AS Domain_End,
  d.ddid,
  d.confid1 AS confid,
  c.pdbcode,
  c.chainid,
  a.pdbcode AS "cath_pdbcode", 
  c.pdbcode
FROM dyn_dyndomrun d
  INNER JOIN dyn_conformer c ON d.confid1 = c.id 
  INNER JOIN dyn_domainregion r ON r.domainid::varchar(8) = d.ddid
  INNER JOIN cath_domains a ON a.pdbcode::character(4) = c.pdbcode
UNION ALL
SELECT
  NULL,
  NULL,
  NULL,
  NULL,
  NULL,
  d.ddid,
  d.confid2,
  c.pdbcode,
  c.chainid
FROM dyn_dyndomrun d 
  INNER JOIN dyn_conformer c ON d.confid2 = c.id
  ORDER BY confid ASC
```